# Changing fluid to pickup for the different agents

Tags: anylogic

Two different agents enter a queue, each with different capacities. I would like the fluid to pickup value to update depending on which agent is pulled out of the queue.

I have tried putting a conditional statement in the fluid to pickup area (if agentOne then 55000 else 70000) but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fluid to pick up should be `agent.capacity`

meaning that the agent itself is holding the value that it will pick up as a parameter that I called capacity